# Duvida sobre RG - qual a melhor forma de controlar o campo?

Tags: data, jquery-masked-input

estou abrindo esse tópico para saber de vocês como tem trabalhado com a questão da inclusão do RG em formulários.

acho que uma preocupação comum de todos quando trabalhamos com formulários é que o controle dos dados fique nas nossas mãos - e não na mao do usuário.

pra isso, qto mais bem formatado e controlado cada campo, melhor.

Um dos meus grandes problema é como controlar o campo de RG.

Até por isso - e pq pra grande maioria dos clientes com que trabalho, o RG é desnecessário - eu de certa forma, acabo convencendo o cliente a "ignorar" o campo em seus formulários, mas, agora estou tendo q trabalhar com o RG que é necessário para um cliente.

Como não tenho tb uma grande experiência nisso gostaria de saber como vocês tem trabalhado com o RG - se estão deixando o campo livre, aberto ou controlando de alguma forma.

Pelo que vi, li, reli, a melhor forma de se controlar o campo é trava-lo para somente dígitos - e formata-lo como XXX.XXX.XXX-X - e informar ao usuário que caso o digito seja "X" (q pelo que vi substitui o 10 no digito) substituir por ZERO.

Não sei se é a melhor forma mesmo - e se isso irá cobrir 100% da realidade dos RGs.. (a única letra q temos no RG é o X no digito?)

Minha necessidade não é um VERIFICADOR - pq isso é impossível - mas sim apenas uma MASCARA de controle - para evitar dados completamente aleatórios e deixar o campo o mais padronizado possível.

o importante é que a mascara seja 100% compatível com todos os tipos de RGs.

Comment: RG muda de estado pra estado, não pode fazer máscara. Ou vai ter que fazer pra cada estado uma diferente. Além disso, você nunca vai saber se o RG foi digitado com ou sem dígito. Tem muito RG antigo que vinha sem, e com máscara o usuário vai por número "normal" no lugar do dígito, causando uma confusão danada. Geralmente a melhor coisa é deixar livre, e apenas colocar um campo extra para informar o estado emissor, e data da emissão. Se o documento é importante demais, simplesmente digitalize.

Answer (score -2):

com o masked input vc deve usar da seguinte forma

```
$("#RG").mask("99.999.999.9?99-*");
```

assim o ultimo campo se torna opcional e a pessoa pode colocar o X caso tenha.

é sempre bom você fazer uma validação de RG tbm olhe este link abaixo para um validador em javascript

http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/codigos/validar-documento-de-identidade-rg

é sempre bom vc impedir de o usuário de fazer "qualquer coisa", isso sempre da problema

Comment: valeu, @jasar-orion ! vou dar uma lida no link - so uma duvida, ainda não testei a mascara - a mascara trabalha com 11 dígitos + o dv - caso o RG tenha so 9 dígitos, ela ira funcionar? E caso não tenha dv?

Comment: corrigi a mascara para aceitar ate 9 dígitos fixamente e 11 opcionalmente. note que tudo depois do ? fica como opcional

Comment: pra que negativar a resposta?

Comment: oi @jasar-orion, so pra esclarecer que nao fui eu q negativei sua resposta, alias eu nunca entendi o que leva uma pessoa a vir num site colaborativo, onde todos estao doando parte do seu tempo para ajudar terceiros completamente desconhecidos e negativar uma resposta - isso pra mim vai contra tudo o que imagino de "fair-play" sabe? A resposta nao sendo ofensiva, pra que fazer isso? Mas eu acho q tem muita gente por ai que acha q sabe tudo e deve achar o maximo fazer esse tipo de coisa.. uma pena..

Comment: concordo , o cara não respeita a boa vontade dos outros, mas o que conta é que se eu te ajudei ou não caso tenha mais dúvidas m avise que farei o possível apar fornecer alguma resposta apropriada.

Answer (score -2):

tem este validador que eu utilizo

```
    function validacpf( cpf )
{
  var i;
  s = cpf;
  var c = s.substr(0,9);
  var dv = s.substr(9,2);
  var d1 = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
  {
    d1 += c.charAt(i)*(10-i);
  }
  if (d1 == 0)
  {
   alert("CPF Invalido");
   return false;
  }
  d1 = 11 - (d1 % 11);
  if (d1 > 9) d1 = 0;
  if (dv.charAt(0) != d1)
  {
   alert("CPF Invalido");
   return false;
  }
  d1 *= 2;
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
  {
   d1 += c.charAt(i)*(11-i);
  }
  d1 = 11 - (d1 % 11);
  if (d1 > 9) d1 = 0;
  if (dv.charAt(1) != d1)
  {
    alert("CPF Invalido");
    return false;
   }
  return true;
 }
```

Comment: Oi @smitherson-da-silva - mas ele é mod11 ne? Pelo que vi o mod11 parece não funcionar com alguns RGs emitidos por alguns estados. vc sabe se isso é verdade? (rg é uma bagunca - vi gente reclamando da verificação por mod 11 - que não funciona - mas não sei ate que ponto é fato ou é pq o usuário estava usando um RG sem digito, por exemplo, como era comum antigamente).

Comment: não sei dizer, sou iniciante e sempre utilizei este script para lojas virtuais de clientes e nunca tive problemas